# Xcode 15 beta 6, SwiftData Framework "Symbol not found" error

Tags: swift, swift-data, xcode15

When building a ios17 app with SwiftData there is an issue with the Framework not being installed as noted on apple dev forums here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734970 my machine does not have the Framework folder for SwiftData, is there a way to manually install the framework? Uninstalling Xcode beta and reinstalling has no effect at this time..

Comment: Submit a bug report